# Can 5 - 3a be described as five minus three times a?

Tags: algebra

The question asks students to describe the expressions in words. This is a student's answer:

"$(x + 4) \times 2$" is "$x$ plus four times two"

"$5 - 3a$" is "five minus three times $a$".

I think one of the answers should be marked as correct. If so, which one is it? Should both of the answers be marked as wrong because they are not clear? Thank you.

Comment: This sounds to me more of an English comprehension issue than a math issue. The main point of such questions is to ensure that students can correctly interpret symbolic expressions, and in the case of the first one, the real issue is whether, if someone asks the student to write "$x$ plus four times two", then the student writes $(x+4) \times 2$ rather than $x + (4)(2).$ The fact that most people would interpret "$x$ plus four times two" as $x + (4)(2)$ is certainly important, and should be pointed out to the student.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro that depends on whether the person learned PEDMAS or not.

Comment: As far as I know, it is generally accepted that mathematical expressions expressed in words become ambiguous - that's in part why we introduce special notation in the first place. It could be a fun exercise to make one student translate it into words and another back into an expression (hopefully, they can come out of this with a greater appreciation for the use of notation).

Comment: What answers did you expect and how would you answer the question yourself?

Comment: @DaveLRenfro _Would_ most people interpret it as $x+4\times 2$? I don't think I would.

Comment: This may be a reason to prefer the nouns "product" and "sum" over the prepositions "times" and "plus", so that $x+4\times 2$ could be read as "the sum of $x$ and the product of 4 and 2", while $(x+4)\times 2$ would be "the product of 2 and the sum of $x$ and 4". I'm not saying I would ever want to say phrases like that outside of a math classroom, but it at least makes the phrases unambiguous. If that was the focus of a lesson (carefully using "sum" and "product"), then I would say both answers are wrong since they are both colloquially used to describe different arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @Adam: In thinking about this now (I just returned to this question), I think when spoken it depends greatly on where someone pauses, if at all, in verbalizing "$x$ plus four times two" -- "$x$ plus [slight pause] four times two [said quickly]" OR "$x$ plus four [slight pause] times two". And thus for a child, it very well could come down to how the child internally reads "$x$ plus four times two", and the child is probably not adept at recognizing how this could be interpreted differently by someone else. Various versions of what Amy B said **(continued)**

Comment: is how I've nearly always heard how people do it, at least if for some reason they don't rephrase it to remove the ambiguity like @user52817 suggests. For the [Jaws screen reader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAWS_(screen_reader)), which I worked with for a few weeks some years ago as part of my job at the time, one would hear something like "left parenthesis x plus four right parenthesis times two" (at a very high speed if an actual listener who is even semi-proficient).

Comment: Another reason the exercise is ill-formed is that is asks the student to "describe" the expression in words. Maybe change the instruction to something like, "Write the expression `(x+4)×2` in words such that your reader can unambiguously recover it from your translation. Then do the same for `x+(4×2)`. The goal is clear communication."

Comment: Putting this link to the "Handbook for Spoken Mathematics" by Larry Chang at the Lawrence Livermore National Lab. https://02522-cua.github.io/lecturenotes/pdf/Chang_1983_Handbook%20for%20Spoken%20Mathematics.pdf See the algebra section starting on page 14 for some opinions on the matter.

Comment: Something like "the sum of x and 4, multiplied by 2" and "the product of 3 and a, subtracted from 5". Commas are essential, without them the meaning will be different.

Comment: @Rusty Indeed. I’m not sure if this is rose-tinted lensing, but it seems that attention to such disambiguating punctuation seems to be rapidly eroding.

Answer (score 4):

If the question is to have any assessment efficacy, then the standard for the answer should be something like "Add 4 to $x$, then multiply the result by 2." For the other example, the answer standard should be "Multiply 3 by $a$, then subtract the result from 5."

Answer (score 1):

"$(x + 4) \times 2$" is incorrect.

It is not  "$x$ plus four times two" because that would be $x + 4 × 2$.

It should be the quantity of $x+4$ times 2.  This shows that the parentheses are there which affects the value.  This is the standard used in the high school I taught.

It seems to me though that this standard should be introduced before giving this assignment. Otherwise - you are left with the confusion of the OP.

I believe the second one is correct.

Comment: I disagree, it's partly just an ill formed question as there isn't a pemdas style standard for written English. Most people seem to use pauses for grouping. i.e. x plus .. 4 times 2 versus x plus 4 ... times 2.  Those aren't present. So what do you do, view it as a series of instructions? That's $(x+4)\times 2$.

Comment: In the spirit of Adam's comment, would "$x$ plus 4, times 2" be acceptable? I personally wouldn't mark it wrong even without the comma because I think it's a bad question (unless the point is to elicit awkward answers to demonstrate the advantages of algebraic notation, in which case it's a good question!)

Comment: @Adam  I edited my answer to indicate that we taught things the way I said I would grade it.  In our HS, the standard was read the parentheses as the quantify of followed by what's in the parentheses.  If no standard is taught then the question is more of a problem.

Comment: @AmyB I think Adam is specifically referring to the verbalisation of those expressions. My take is that the given exercise is teaching students to recognise potential for ambiguity, rather than checking their interpretation of those symbolic arithmetic expressions.

Comment: "The double sum of x and 4" -> $(x+4)\times 2$. "The sum of x and the double of 4" -> $x+4\times 2$.